# Changing the sender's email address

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

Ive created below script to automatically send emails when the checkbox is ticked. My problem is, the sheet is being used by two users and I want to **change the sender** so that the email will be sent out from the **user who triggered the script**.

I've tried adjusting the "Deployment" settings so that the app script runs as the "User accessing the Web app", also asked the other user to create a trigger of his own, which is working fine. But we are getting two emails (probably because of the two triggers?) Looking for advice on how do I go about it.

```
function onCheckboxEdit(e) {
  var source = e.source;
  var sheet = source.getActiveSheet() ;
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  console.log("column:: ", column);

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 13, 1, 7);
  var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
  console.log("targetRange:: ", targetValues);
  var recipient = targetValues[0][2];
  var checkboxValue = targetValues[0][4];
  var body = targetValues[0][1];
  var Replacement = targetValues [0][0];
  var subject = "Replacement for " + Replacement;
  var ccmail = targetValues[0][3];
  var Rname = targetValues[0][5];
  var EMAIL_SENT = 'E-mail sent';
  var emailDupe = targetValues[0][6]; 

  if(emailDupe !== 'E-mail sent' && checkboxValue  == true) {
    console.log("checkbox marked true")

    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {cc:ccmail,
    name: Rname})
    sheet.getRange(row, 19).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)

  }else if (column = 17 && checkboxValue == false) {
    console.log("checkbox marked false")
  }else {
    console.log("No clue")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a domain version of  Google workspace?

Comment: you mean the account we're using? yes, we're using our google accounts

Comment: Is it paid or personal?

Comment: paid, a company google domain

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Google workspace domain, you may be able to get the email of the  effective user and the active user and compare it to stop double triggers.

```
function onCheckboxEdit(e) {
  const eUser/*User who owns the trigger*/ = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  const aUser/*current user at the keyboard*/ = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  console.log({time: new Date(), aUser, eUser});
  if (aUser !== eUser) return;

  /*rest of the code*/
  var source = e.source;
  /*...*/
}
```

Check the logs for actual logged value and change the `if` statements accordingly.

Comment: I tried inserting this one. Strangely, it didn't produce any logs...Sorry if Im missing anything, I just started doing this last weekend

Comment: @josh_97 Someone should actually make the edit for it to trigger the script

Comment: @josh_97 By "edit", I mean "checkbox" click